# connect method in QT GUI does not work

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a console QT application. Now I need to add GUI to it. So I created a new GUI application and add my console application source file to GUI application. I add a pushbutton that does not work. I guess the connect() does not work since the myapp->start() is not called. But what is the correct way to trigger the event?

Here is the header file:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:
        void startProgram();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;  
        MyApp *myapp;
        QPushButton *startButton;
};
```

Here is the source file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myapp = new MyApp;
    startButton = new QPushButton("Start");
    QObject::connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,  SLOT(startProgram()) );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::startProgram()
{
    myapp->start();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a segfault, have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: It crashed where? What is console output? You provide no information.

Comment: The crash is fixed. Now my problem is that the connect does not actually trigger the myapp->start(). Is there something wrong with the GUI wrapper?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in tiny snippet. But look on console. Qt will tell you if your slot is actually connected. You should also not use SIGNAL and SLOT macros anymore. Use `connect(startButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::startProgram)` then you'll see at compile time if things actually connect.

Comment: This does not work neither. When I click the button, the slot is not triggered and I can see the output is not correct in console. However, if I define the pushbuttion in main.cpp and move connect() to main.cpp, it works. Why?

Comment: Your code is creating a button as independent window (no parent), and not showing it. Either you code here is not representative of your real code, or you are clicking some different start button (perhaps created with Designer).

Answer (score 2):

Have you created startButton in QtCreator because you are not adding it to any widget or layout in the code?

If that is the case, you are probably creating a new startButton in the MainWindow constructor. When the application starts you are pressing the startButton created in the QtCreator but the button has not been connected to any slots. The startButton created in the MainWindow is not shown in the UI at all.

Just check what is the object name of the startButton in the QtCreator and connect it to startProgram() -slot. The connection must be done after the initialization of the UI ( ui->setupUi(this); ).